# How to embed or-tools in a C# application?

Tags: c#, or-tools

I'm trying to follow the instructions at https://developers.google.com/optimization/introduction/installing.html#windows_binary so that I can use or-tools inside my C# application.

I'm stuck on the `make all` step. I am in the Developer Command Prompt, but this command says:

```
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I tried downloading GNU make, but that fails also. `make install` says "no target", and a bare `make` says:

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cl /EHsc /MD /nologo /D_SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -nologo /O2 -DNDEBUG -DUSE_CBC -DUSE_CLP /D__WIN32__ /Iinclude\src\windows /DGFLAGS_DLL_DECL= /DGFLAGS_DLL_DECLARE_FLAG= /DGFLAGS_DLL_DEFINE_FLAG= /Iinclude /Iexamples -DUSE_GLOP -DUSE_BOP -c examples\cpp\costas_array.cc /Foobjs\costas_array.obj, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [objs\\costas_array.obj] Error 2
```

I also tried copying the DLLs from the `bin` folder directly into my project. I was able to compile against them by doing this, but when I tried to run it I got an error:

```
System.BadImageFormatException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Google.OrTools, Version=5.1.6235.37215, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7a052e3db761d3be' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the System.BadImageFormatException:

The OrTools binary format is provided in a 64bit dll.

Make sure, that your project is set to 64bit:

In Visual Studio you can check it out by right clicking on the Project --> Properties --> Build, Platform Target: This should be set to x64.

Comment: thank you for the tip ... the project is apparently linked to some other libraries that break when I do this. Will see if I can get updated versions of them. (https://bitbucket.org/Nicksaurus/foreman/src/46053dff1b7ab1be40ddb61a519d7cb6fbf18632/lib/?at=default , fwiw)

Comment: updated other libs, this appears it might work. Leaving open for now because I'm still curious about the make thing, but will accept as answer in a couple of days if no one else chimes in.

Answer (score 2):

In case you have the same issue with web application, just enable 64 bits on IIS Express using `Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Web Projects -> Use the 64-bit version on IIS Express for web sites and projects`
[image: Visual Studio 2019]

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue when using OR-Tools in a Web Application (it worked fine in a console application). I was getting:

System.BadImageFormatException HResult=0x8007000B Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Google.OrTools' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Using x64 didn't help, and Octopus was not building the project correctly either.  The solution that worked for me was specifying which ASPNETCOMPILER to use (x64) in the project's .csproj :

```
<Project .... >
   <PropertyGroup>
      <AspNetToolPath>$(windir)\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319</AspNetToolPath>
   </PropertyGroup>
```